# Запрос sql для создания базы данных

Tags: sql-server

Создал таблицы для базы данных, хочу создать query, чтобы можно было воссоздать мою БД.

использую sql server 2008 
Запускаю запрос, показывает время и написан: debbuging query  итак уже 10 мин и все идет время. Я так  понимаю где то ошибка? А с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: А почему Вы не используете стандартные средства резервного копирования? Тем более существует возможность сохранения в sql-файл.

Comment: хочу человеку выслать и чтобы он создал у себя эту БД

Comment: Посмотрите в админке, там есть возможность создания скрипта. А вообще выложите код.

Comment: @dev85 а что значит воссоздать? Вы хотите получить скрипт создания вашей БД?

Answer (score 1):

Вы запрос как-то неправильно запускаете: должно выводиться Executing query :) 
Нажмите другую кнопку (на ней нарисован красный знак восклицания) или F5.